# Sorting JSON by key

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have this JSON string:

```
{
  "name": ".",
  "_type": "folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Beverages",
      "_type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Water",
          "_type": "file"
        },
        {
          "name": "Tea",
          "_type": "folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "White tea",
              "_type": "file"
            },
            {
              "name": "Green tea",
              "_type": "folder",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Sencha",
                  "_type": "file"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Pi Lo Chun",
                  "_type": "file"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Matcha",
                  "_type": "file"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Gyokuro",
                  "_type": "file"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Black tea",
              "_type": "file"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Coffee",
          "_type": "file"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It represents this folder:

```
│
└───Beverages
    │   Coffee
    │   Water
    │
    └───Tea
        │   Black tea
        │   White tea
        │
        └───Green tea
                Gyokuro
                Matcha
                Pi Lo Chun
                Sencha
```

The problem is that the JSON is ordered by the anti-lexicographical order: you can see `Water-Tea-Coffee` under `Beverages`. That is, it rather represents this structure:

```
.
|
`- Beverages
   |
   +- Water
   |
   +- Tea
   |  |
   |  +- White tea
   |  |
   |  +- Green tea
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Sencha
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Pi Lo Chun
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Matcha
   |  |  |
   |  |  `- Gyokuro
   |  |
   |  `- Black tea
   |
   `- Coffee
```

But `Tea` is a folder, while `Water` and `Coffee` are files (they don't have children). I'd like to have the folders following by the files, as in the first tree picture.

Comment: Sorry I don't see how the "duplicate" helps. I don't have an array and there is some nesting.

Comment: That works by applying the method to each children (a child is an array) but how to do recursively?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, the duplicate you have mentioned does not actually help here.

Comment: you can achieve it using recursive in-place sorting => https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-3bdru4?file=/index.js

Comment: Thank you @AmilaSenadheera! It works. I just exchanged -1 and 1. Shame to the closer! ;-)